# List index out of range, JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build a function that will allow me to easily get cryptocurrency data. Here is what I have (which came from a tutorial online)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import time
from datetime import date
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def timestamp2date(timestamp):
    # function converts a Unix timestamp into Gregorian date
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def date2timestamp(date):
    # function coverts Gregorian date in a given format to timestamp
    return datetime.strptime(date_today, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()


def fetchCryptoOHLC(fsym, tsym):
    # function fetches a crypto price-series for fsym/tsym and stores
    # it in pandas DataFrame

    cols = ['date', 'timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
    lst = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']

    timestamp_today = datetime.today()
    curr_timestamp = timestamp_today

    for j in range(2):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
        url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=" + fsym + "&tsym=" + tsym + "&toTs=" + str(curr_timestamp) + "&limit=2000"
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        dic = json.loads(soup.prettify())
        for i in range(1, 2001):
            tmp = []
            for e in enumerate(lst):
                x = e[0]
                y = dic['Data'][i][e[1]]
                if(x == 0):
                    tmp.append(str(timestamp2date(y)))
                tmp.append(y)
            if(np.sum(tmp[-4::]) > 0):
                df.loc[len(df)] = np.array(tmp)
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
        df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
        curr_timestamp = int(df.ix[0][0])
        if(j == 0):
            df0 = df.copy()
        else:
            data = pd.concat([df, df0], axis=0)

    return data
```

The problem I am having is when running the fetchCryptoOHLC function, I am stuck with this error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: The traceback you received with the error message should tell you where in the code the problem occurred. Please edit your post to include that information.

Comment: `for i in range(1, 2001):` seems suspicious. List indexes start at 0, not 1. My guess is it should be `for i in range(0, 2000):`

Comment: Or just do `for datum in dic['Data']:`